# Virtual device target (Android null) - Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-virtual-device, virtual-device-manager, avd-manager

I am facing an issue which I am trying to solve for 2 days now and seem to be missing something out.

I have reinstalled Android Studio into custom location to save some space of my C: drive, and made the necessary adjustments to my environmental variable. However, the AVD is not picking up my new installation in the correct way. The following picture shows the problem:

[image]

I am in complete loss on where to start to troubleshoot this problem and get to figure out what I have done to miss it up.

Any thoughts ?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? I'm having the same problem

Answer (score 1):

Try to **Sync project with Gradle files**

If that doesn´t help, restart and invalidate caches and sync again.